# How to refresh layer style correctly while setting to group

Tags: qgis, pyqgis, style, qgis-2, group-layer

I have almost finished to implement the following idea:

When moving a raster layer to a distinct group load a style from a QML style file.

I'm using this code in the Python console in QGIS:

```
def isInstanceOfGroup():
    root = QgsProject.instance().layerTreeRoot()
    subchild_list = []
    for child in root.children():
        for subchild in child.children():
            if isinstance(subchild, QgsLayerTreeLayer):
                if subchild.parent().name() == 'MyGroup':
                    subchild_list.append(subchild.layerName())

    layer = iface.activeLayer()    
    if iface.activeLayer().name() in subchild_list:
        layer.loadNamedStyle('c:/path_to_style_file/test.qml')
        layer.triggerRepaint()
    else:
        pass

iface.legendInterface().currentLayerChanged.connect(isInstanceOfGroup)
```

Two things that do not work properly:

1. When I move a layer to the group it don't sets the style when I release the layer (left mouse button). It sets the style when I click on more time on layer.
2. After the layer is clicked the style is set but the legend has not changed. It changed until I move the layer within the group one more time.

What do I have to change that after releasing/dropping the layer to the group style/legend are changed immediately?

Comment: yes is normal currentLayerChanged is a signal for detect if the click layer change,not for detect TOC movement

Comment: @FranciscoRaga - Is there a signal for detecting TOC movement?

Comment: I think not,but I'm not sure